Proof of decomposition of policy performance
this is a proof of a lemma 1 from the TRPO paper by Schulman et al about decomposition of policy performance. I have rewritten it down in a notation that I prefer:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t A_\pi(S_t, A_t)\right] & =\mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\gamma^t (r(S_t) + \gamma V_{\pi}(S_{t+1}) - V_{\pi}(S_t))\right] \\ & = \mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}[-V_{\pi}(S_0) + \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\gamma^t r(S_t)] \\ & = -\mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}[V_{\pi}(S_0)] + \mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\gamma^t r(S_t)] \\ & = -\eta(\pi) + \eta(\tilde{\pi})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
I don't see here how $\eta(\pi)=\mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}[V_{\pi}(S_0)]$ since the state $S_0$ is sampled from the stationary distribution $d^\tilde{\pi}$ rather then $d^\pi$. Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?
